# Draw directly to PictureBox

Tags: c#, multithreading, picturebox, invoke

I'm developing a **screen-sharing app** which runs a loop constantly and receives small frames from a socket. The next step is to draw them into the **PictureBox**.
Of course, I use thread because I don't want to freeze the ui.

This is my code:

```
 Bitmap frame = byteArrayToImage(buff) as Bitmap;//a praticular bitmap im getting from a socket.
 Bitmap current =  (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
 var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(current);
 graphics.DrawImage(frame, left, top);//left and top are two int variables of course.
 pictureBox1.Image = current;
```

But now I'm getting an error:

> Object is already in use elsewhere.

in this line `var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(current);`

Tried to `Clone` it, Create a `New Bitmap(current)`. still no success.

Comment: You create a Graphics context from the Image, this doesn't have a direct reference to your image any more inside the picturebox, it's just a new version of the image. You have to set the image again into the picturebox afterwards

Comment: In fact you ARE manipulating the very instance of the picture that also  `pictureBox1` holds (or what do you mean by "direct reference", Icepickle?). The only problem is that `pictureBox1` simply does not know about the changes you made to its `Image` - so it does not redraw itself. Try calling `pictureBox1.Refresh()` or `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` (following Icepickle's suggestion: `pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image;` should work as well - decide for yourself)

Comment: Huh?...I agree with olydis.  Just refresh your picturebox and it should update!

Comment: @Icepickle look my post i edited it. thanks for the help!

Comment: @olydis i just tried use them both.. they wory very very slow.(measured the time) they  slow down the loop execution time... have any other suggestion? but thanks though!

Comment: @Slashy: despite being slow, did it solve the problem? What "loop" are you talking about??? My psychic powers are telling me that you are calling `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` inside that loop? Is calling it **afterwards** an option?

Comment: Instead of giving us **symptoms** of the problem(s), how about you describe **what you're actually trying to do**.  How and why are you using the above code?  How often are you attempting to update the image?  Why are you using a different thread? etc...

Comment: @Idle_Mind alright i will edit in a second. You right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalidate() your PictureBox so it redraws itself:

```
Bitmap frame = byteArrayToImage(buff) as Bitmap;
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    graphics.DrawImage(frame, left, top);
}
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

If you need it to be thread safe, then:

```
pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    Bitmap frame = byteArrayToImage(buff) as Bitmap;
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(frame, left, top);
    }
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
});
```

Comment: i just tried invalidate but it's **very very very** slow and make the whole drawing process goes slow.. please see my last lines in my question i've just edited it. now i assign the new image to the picturebox control but im still getting an excpetion. thanks !!

Comment: Note how in my example there is a `using` block to properly dispose of the graphics.  This should get rid of the error you're seeing.

Comment: see post again please. just edited it. thanks for everything!